# Conditional Filling Polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, conditional, formatting

Is it possible to conditionally fill in county polygon of a state based on a date field?

**Example**:

ABCD County has a plan that was approved by FEMA on 10/01/2015 and expires on 09/30/2020. 
For ABCD county polygon I want to show "Green" until the current date is 2 years out.

Once the plan is two years from expiring I want the county polygon to turn "Yellow" automatically.

Then once the plan expires, I want the county polygon to turn "Red" until the date field for the county polygon is updated with a five (5) year out or greater.

---

Here is a sample of the project.[[image: Hazard Mitigation County Status map. Anything counties with a Hazard Mitigation plan expiring within 2 year will turn yellow. This does not reflect anything current. This is strictly just a sample of the map I have generated.]

Comment: Asking for a tutorial to be written makes this too broad.

Comment: I have gone in and shortened my question. I hope that this fits within the rules. I am just trying to learn conditional formatting and was trying to provide as much information as possible  in a non-confusing way to users that would be able to answer and help me learn. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: What have you tried? At the moment your question only says what you want to do, and not where you are stuck.

Comment: I'm stuck on adding a "Date" attribute field and assigning a specific color based on a date in the 'date field'. I know the concept of the conditional feature. I just don't know if the specific utilization of this feature is possible.

Comment: Below is a link to an example of the general concept of what i am looking for, however, within this article it doesn't provide how to get these conditional rules to work. Also, would this be the same concept for a polygon for states and county polygons? I appreciate any guidance I can get from you and the other users in this community. 
https://nathanw.net/2012/01/25/improvements-to-the-qgis-rule-based-rendering/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is more than just filling in a color based on a date. You want live-updating styling based on the difference between a date field and the current date. You will need to create a virtual field.

For this example, I will assume that the field for the expiration date is called Expiration_Date. Use the field calculator to add a virtual field to calculate how many days from now the plan will expire. Call the field Time_Left and use this expression:

> day( age( "Expiration_Date", now()) )

Now set up rule-based formatting as such:

> Rule 1:  "Time_Left" > 730
>
> Rule 2:  "Time_Left" <= 730 AND "Time_Left" > 0
>
> Rule 3:  "Time_Left" <= 0

Format Rule 1 as green, rule 2 as yellow and rule 3 as red. This will turn the county green when the plan has more than two years left before it expires, yellow when it has two or fewer years left, and red when the plan is expired.

This method achieves most of what you asked for, but it doesn't have the county stay red after the plan expires until the plan is updated with more than five years until it expires. That's a much more complicated problem, and beyond my ability.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I know it has been a few months since I ask however. I finally got back around to this project and your answer helped out tremendously!

Comment: I already did mark it as answered yesterday. Is it not reflecting as "Answered" now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this and there are several tutorials out there.

You need rule based styles.

Here is one example:  https://nathanw.net/2011/06/06/one-of-my-favorite-features-of-qgis/